# Handle specific types in a generic method takes and returns the same generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method `T foo(T)` which, depending on the actual type of the argument, performs different operations. Following is an example that illustrates the same problem. (See below for a description of what I'm actually doing in my code.)

```
<T extends Number> T foo(T a) {
    if (a instanceof Integer) {
        return ((Integer) a) + 1;
    } else if (a instanceof Double) {
        return ((Double) a) + 1;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This does not violate the requirement of the return type but it is not accepted by `javac`. The problem is that e.g. the `return ((Integer) a) + 1;` will only ever be executed when `T` is `Integer` but the compiler can't (according to the JLS) infer this and thus expects that a `T` is passed to `return`. The expression there is typed as `int`, which can't be converted to `T`.

Is there a way to deal with this situation without resorting to an unchecked cast?

---

What I'm actually doing in my code: In the application, there's a generic interface which is used to encapsulate some value. There are different specialized implementations of that interface for different value types and the method I'm trying to write should dynamically chose the right implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are type-checking `a` at runtime, then you are defeating the point of generics.  But generics don't work with mathematical operators anyway, because those operators work with primitives and type parameters work with reference types.  Your workaround doesn't work with the compiler because `T` could be any `Number` type at compile time, so the compiler can't allow you to return an `Integer` when it thinks it could be any `Number` type.

Instead, I would overload two non-generic `foo` methods -- one with `int` and one with `double`.  Neither of these methods would be generic, and each would just perform its own operation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't proper use of generics. You should use [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) instead

Comment: I only know the type at run-time, thus method overloading does not work.